# How to bring the top panel to the bottom from command line?

Tags: 10.10, panel

I would like to bring that top panel to bottom via command line. Is there any command to do that from terminal? I have searched everywhere, i haven't find one. Can any one share a command to bring the top panel to bottom?

**Note:**

I just prefer command line coz i have to do it in all remote machines. I know the way to bring the panel to bottom via GUI method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `gconftool-2` to do this.

Using the GUI tool gconf-editor:

[image]

The top-panel is found in the key *orientation* in the path `/apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0`

You will see in the GUI tool the values this key takes - thus to force the top-panel to move to the bottom you would use:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/orientation "bottom"
```

the parameters are

1. `-t string` which means the value to set is a string value
2. `-s` which means set the key where this is the full path including the key-name
3. "bottom" - this is the string value for the key